# If I want a function only applies to the elements of a specific list, how should I define the function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

If I define a list:

```
list={1,2,3,4};
```

and I want a function `f` to apply only to the elements in the list (for here it is 1,2,3,4), how should I do this?

```
f[n_???]:=...
```

Comment: [Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but f applies to elements via Map, so  ´f/@ list´ does the job

Comment: Check out [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
f[n_] := n
f[n_?(MemberQ[list, #] &)] := n^2

f /@ Range@10
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```